# stop Sync between laptop and pc

Tags: windows, windows-10, sync

I have a problem between my laptop and pc because the applications on the background are the same, idk how to turn this off even though I turned off the sync option in windows itself.

For example, if I have Netflix on my background on my laptop it will also appear on my pc (which I don't want) so I delete it from my pc desktop but then it will be also removed from my laptop.

any help would be helpful or in case there is already an answer to this pls link me, kinda newbie here

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

- Run *Settings*
- Position to *Accounts > Sync your settings*
- Turn "Sync settings" to Off.

You might need to repeat this on both computers and to reboot.